# Is there any way to get Gitlab group runner registration token via API?

Tags: bash, curl, gitlab, wget, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to create new local **GROUP** runner with docker executor using a bash script.

I want to make the script generic and reusable.

Right now, I wrote the registration token hard-coded in my script:

```bash
export GITLAB_RUNNER_TOKEN=*my-token*

sudo -E sh .local_runner.sh
```

I looked in the [group API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/groups.html) and in the [runners API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/runners.html) and I didn't find a way to get the registration code via API.

I want to avoid a situation when someone in my organization will reset the token and my script w'ont work.

Is there any way to achieve that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's accessible in Groups API: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/groups.html#details-of-a-group

Here is a curl example with `jq` to exctract token only:

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: YOUR_TOKEN" "https://gitlab.example.invalid/api/v4/groups/YOUR_GROUP_ID?with_projects=no" --silent| jq '.runners_token'
```

Replace your token, gitlab url and group id with relevant info.

`?with_projects=no` limits scope of request to group info only, which can reduce query response times for groups with dozens of projects.